# Pass additional parameters to a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this link to create a new page:

```
<p><%= link_to "Add a page", :action => "new" %></p>
```

The code called in the controller is this:

```
def new
  @page = Page.new
  @visuals = Visual.find(:all)
end
```

I would like to pass an additional parameter to pre-set a field in the form, something like this:

```
<p><%= link_to "Add a page", :action => "new/parent_id/2" %></p>
```

and in the controller

```
def new
  @page = Page.new
  @page.parent_id = params[:parent_id]
  @visuals = Visual.find(:all)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
link_to "new", :action => 'new', :parent_id => 1
```

... will give you:

```
/controller/new?parent_id=1
```

If you mess with the routes, you could do:

```
map.new_page_from_parent "/new_from_parent/:parent_id"
```

... and use like so:

```
link_to "new", new_page_from_parent_path(:parent_id => 1)

# gives
/new_from_parent/1

# accessed via
params[:parent_id] => 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a new parameter without changing routes, just pass it in as a query string:

```
new?parent_id=2
```

then it will be available to you as `params[:parent_id]`